# Wipe Emulator Data while running

Tags: android, testing, emulation

Is it possible to get a clean emulator state even in runtime? I need to test several Apps, and need a clean state before testing each app. I can easily do this with deleting all the created  files like `userdata.img` or `cache.img` but then i need to reboot the emulator which takes about 2 minutes on my TestVM...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your applications' modifiable files live in well-known directories, such as `getFilesDir()`. Simply delete the files before launching your test suite.

If you do not trust that approach, then you can uninstall the app before installing it and running your test suite. That will not get rid of files on external storage, but it will clear out internal storage, so whether or not this is sufficiently a "clean slate" for you, I cannot say.

If those (or their combination) is insufficient, then you have no choice but to wipe out and restart the emulator. You can always purchase a faster development machine, or see if running the emulator in headless mode will speed up its launch.

Comment: The problem is i test apps which could modify anything inside the emulator, even /system files. So i need a real clean state, which means in best case i make a tar of my clean emulator and extract it each time to the .avd directory. And yes of course i could probably buy me a more expensive machine but for that i would need some money ;) A normal Emulator starts up in <20secs, the problem is i'm using a custom kernel and custom android as well, thats why the startup took so long

Comment: @reox: "The problem is i test apps which could modify anything inside the emulator, even /system files." -- then, by definition, you have no choice but to restore the emulator from scratch.

Comment: so there is definitly no way to tell the qemu to just reset its current fileset on the partition to this state in the runtime?

Comment: @reox: Not that I am aware of. After all, qemu has already changed the files. Unless there's something magic in the snapshot mechanism you could use, I see no way for qemu to magically go back in time to some version of the files from before it made the changes requested by your test suite.